# How to get flatten JSON result with MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation

After aggregating, I get a not expected output. Is there anything I could do?

```
aggregate([ 
            { "$match": {
                "CREATE_DATE": {
                    "$lte": new Date(),
                    "$gte": new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
                       Date().getDate()-120))
                }
            } },
            { "$group": {
                "_id": { 
                    "month": { "$month": "$CREATE_DATE" },
                    "year": { "$year": "$CREATE_DATE" }
                },
                "avgofozone": { "$avg": "$OZONE" }
            } }

        ])
```

**Actual Output:**

> ```
> [
>     { "avgofozone" : 21.07777777777778, "year" : 2018, "month" : 2 }
>     { "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 3 }
>     { "avgofozone" : 17.8, "year" : 2018, "month" : 1 }
> ]
> ```

**Expected Output:**

> ```
>     [
>         { 
>             "zone_type": "avgofozone", 
>             "year": 2018, 
>             "February": 21.07777777777778, 
>             "March": 17.8, 
>             "January": 17.8 
>         }
>     ]
> ```

Comment: Could you please post a sample input document?

Comment: @  Vega we can display month name integer no prob
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a65b71a3071ebb37576b3b56"),
    "ID" : "20180120210013631847000000",
    "DISTRICT" : "ntvp",
    "STATION" : "APPCB",
    "OZONE" : 25.0,
    "FLAG1" : "NA",
    "AMMONIA" : 11.4,
    "BENZENE" : 6.7,
    "FLAG2" : "NA",
    "FLAG3" : "NA",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-03-20T18:32:50.000Z"),
    "DATA_FROM" : "Gtuy"
}

Comment: @ Vega
my expected output is every month number replace to avgofozone thatas all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MongoDB >= v3.4.4 you can add the following stages to the end of your existing pipeline which will do the transformation for you:

```
{
    $addFields: {
        result: {
            $let: {
                vars: { "months": [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ], arr: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } },
                in: {
                    "k" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$months" , { $subtract: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr.v" , 2 ] }, 1 ] } ] },
                    "v" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr.v" , 0 ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$year",
        result: { $push: "$result" },
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "result": { $arrayToObject: "$result" },
    }
}, {
    $addFields: {
        "result.zonetype": "avgofozone",
        "result.year": "$_id"
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$result"
    }
}
```

Comment: @ dnickless  iam trying this code to display error message .."errmsg" : "unknown group operator '$mergeObjects'",

Comment: @ dnickless  my mongodb version 3.4

Comment: Kindly see my updated answer which should work from 3.4.4 onwards

Comment: @ dnickless i got the output pettaran but some mistake avarageozone replaced by year like this
{
    "Jan" : 2018,
    "Mar" : 2018,
    "zonetype" : "avgofozone",
    "year" : 2018
}

Comment: I presume you are using Robo3T to run this query? There seems to be a funky bug - I got the same behaviour. Try running the query using mongo.exe instead.

Comment: Ah, I got the query to work properly in Robo3T by adding the square brackets around all pipeline stages, so .aggregate( **[** {/*stage1*/},{/*stage2*/},{...} **]** ) instead of just .aggregate({/*stage1*/},{/*stage2*/},{...})

Comment: @  dnickless  "v" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr.v" , 0 ] }  replaced "v" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$$arr.v" , 1 ] } i got the output but any possible take year raplace by DATA_FROM field please suggest me

Comment: @ dnickless out put is ok but how add _id :DATA_FROM   in the above query

Comment: These indices in the $arrayElemAt refer to the positions of the respective fields in what you called "Actual Output" in your question. So if you haven't changed your original pipeline definition and if the "Actual Output" matches exactly what you are showing above then the indices I used in my answer should be correct. Regarding the other question about the _id:DATA_FROM I don't understand what you mean. Perhaps you could update your question above?